# A simple assumption when deriving the fundamental solution of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

When deriving the fundamental solution in his book PDE (section 2.3.1, page 46), Evans comes to the equation
$$r^{n-1}w'+\frac{1}{2}r^n w=a,$$
where $w:=w(y)=w(|y|)=w(r)$. After that he assumes that if $\lim_{r \rightarrow\infty}w, w'=0$, then $a=0$. But if so, we will have $\lim_{r \rightarrow\infty}(r^{n-1}w')=\infty\cdot0$ and $\lim_{r \rightarrow\infty}(r^{n}w)=\infty\cdot0$.

Applying the L'Hospital's Rule wouldn't help much since we don't know the behaviour of higher derivatives of $w$. My question is how to obtain the result $a=0$? I suppose it is pretty straight forward, but unfortunately can't see it.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Could someone please give a hand on this :)